# How do I perform a memory-efficient array sort in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, memory

I'm wanting to sort a large array of Strings (notably `File.list()`, which I cannot externalise or reduce further) without using [much] extra memory.

`Arrays.sort()` says it does a merge sort, and wikipedia says that some implementations allocate the size of the original array for storing the sorted output. (This seems to be supported by the `System.arraycopy` reference in the method).

Is there an in-place sorting algorithm I can use instead which is memory efficient?

Comment: How complex a sort algorithm are you happy to write by hand, and do you want it to be stable (meaning that elements of equal value appear in the final array in the same order that they appeared to begin with)? Not that you can really tell the difference with String unless you start looking at `System.identityHashcode` or whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

quicksort is in-place and very fast. See [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html#quicksort_implementation).

Comment: Ok - that's great; does apache or google have a lib with a quicksort in it? (I'm sure I've seen one before...)

Comment: quicksort is very fast, but it's also one of the more expensive sorts, memory-wise

Comment: @Sam Quicksort can be implemented in-place, which I believe makes it fine memory-wise.

Comment: @Sam: eh? Quicksort uses O(log n) additional memory, and that's in the expected case if written badly and the worst case if written well.

Comment: Oddly enough, from the Javadoc it looks like `Arrays.sort` is implemented with quicksort for primitives and mergesort for Objects.

Comment: @Michael: that's because a stable sort is meaningless/pointless for primitive types (almost - consider negative zero for floats!), but might be meaningful/useful for object types depending how they're compared.

Comment: so log2n of 1000000 (files) is 20 * 2-3 objects at each recursion is around the size of 100 object references, which is rather pale compared to the file name length etc

Comment: @Sam: of course, but the variable use of a quicksort is, as Stephen says, only a few offsets per level of recursion, and at most `log n` levels of recursion if written well. Given that we're comparing it with a mergesort that copies all or half of the input array, it is not "one of the more expensive sorts memory-wise". But it's not really in-place as dlev said, and it does use more stack than, say, insertion sort.

Answer (score 5):

`String` is immutable in Java. Thus when the array of `String`s in your question are duplicated, they do not require as much space as you expect. Actually, the overhead can be quite minimal.

In other words, Java's `Arrays#sort()` can be just fine for your solution. You may test the performance yourself.

For your title of the question, [Ankit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418235/ankit)'s answer and [dlev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/675502/dlev)'s answer are just fine.

Comment: To be clear, what will be duplicated is only the array of object *references* (typically 4 or 8 bytes per string) not the String objects themselves, and therefore not the character arrays inside each String.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an Heap Sort algorithm for in-place sorting.